# Cook boneless skinless chicken thigh portions to taste like drumsticks?

Tags: chicken

Can I cook boneless skinless chicken thigh portions to taste like drumsticks?

My store doesn't have IQF (individually quick frozen) drumsticks, so I
bought IQF boneless skinless chicken thigh portions, on the theory
that they're both dark meat.

Unfortunately, the thighs have a LOT more fat and actually made me a
little naseous.

Is there any way to cook thighs to taste more like drumsticks? For
example, somehow draining more fat out of them or something?

Answer (score 3):

Prick holes in the skin, rub salt, lemon juice, garlic/pepper/chilli etc. into the skins and cook under a grill (US = 'broiler', I think) for a tasty, crispy-skinned treat. If you cut the 'flap' of meat off the thigh and cook separately the bit with the bone makes a v. good drumstick substitute. In fact I prefer them.

Incidentally, if the thighs you get are really fatty, perhaps you could switch to a different butcher/supermarket/brand? Organic, free-range chicken is leaner (because the birds get to move around more) and sweeter because they haven't been fed rubbish.

Your karma and tastebuds will thank you for it ;-)

Bon Appetit!